# Auto rebase on main update

Tags: git, automation, rebase

Does anyone know a way so that everytime the main/master branch is updated all the other remote branches rebase from it. My setup is as follows I and my colleagues each have our own branch. The only time there occurs a push on the main branch is when the new features are implemented and we already decided which part of which branches we are going to use. We would like to like to make human failure as little as possible so we would like to rebase the branches of each colleague automatically.
Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

As of know one of us just goes through every branch and rebases them by hand.

Comment: Even if you could automate the rebase, that would happen on the remote, meaning that you and all your colleagues would still have to do a reset on your machine: that wouldn't make your life easier compared to doing a rebase yourselves.. or did I miss something?

Comment: Well something I didn't mention was that I have a script that puts all my local branches onto the HEAD of remote by OS start.